# Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi I have an invalid sql statement error. This is my code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb   'For OleDbConnection 
Imports System.Data         'For ConnectionState 


Public Class WebForm1

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        '1 declare the variables
        Dim strName As String = txtName.Text
        Dim strAddress As String = txtAddress.Text


        '2. creates a new connection to your DB.
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\GT\Documents\Database11.accdb'")
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If

        '3. open the connection to your DB. 
        conn.Open()

        '4. assign your SQL statement into sqlString variable. 
        Dim sqlString As String
        sqlString = "INSERT INTO tblStuInfo (stuName, stuAddress) VALUES ('" & strName & "' , '" & strAddress & "')"

        '5. create a new command that links your SQL statement with your connection. 
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand(sqlString, conn)

        '6. execute your command.
        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What is the problem? The path of the database and the table name of the DB is correct. Please help!

Comment: You have a sql injection error there. Use a parameterised SqlCommand.

Comment: How do i do that? btw this is a tutorial i followed from a book

Comment: How can I make my code work? What is wrong?

Comment: Read this: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: I dont want to use  parameterised SqlCommand, this tutorial is from a book. What is wrong in my code? I followed it correctly but get that error

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO tblStuInfo (stuName, stuAddress) VALUES ('"
    & strName & "' , '" & strAddress & "')"
```

with

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO tblStuInfo (stuName, stuAddress) VALUES ('"
    & strName.Replace("'", "''") & "' , '" & strAddress.Replace("'", "''") & "')"
```

this should solve any SQL injection issue, that happen when your string contain the **'** character.

Anyway, I think you should add (or use) a key in the underlying table, otherwise how are you going to get these values back?

Comment: Ya that works but why in the tutorial it doesn't mention to use the "replace"?

Comment: Maybe because the issue will only happen if `strAddress` contains a single quote? The query seems to be OK in the case where `strAddress` doesn't have any quotes?

Comment: @user3414064 (wild guess) maybe because the tutorial is about vb.net, and not about SQL (so it take for granted that you already know tricks and quirks of SQL) - Or maybe it' because it's a tutorial, ant things get introduced a tiny bit at time, and managing string delimiter in sql is considered an 'advanced topic' by the tutorial

Comment: No Im sure the tutorial is correct and im certain I followed it correctly. Here it is: http://www.sendspace.com/file/r2g7fq

Comment: What could be the problem?

Comment: @user3414064 nothing wrong on your side, the author of the tutorial didn't consider the management of string delimiter (not in this lesson at least), maybe he treated the management of SQL string delimiter is in another lesson :-)

Comment: @user3414064 the issue caused by the ' character is explained here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/

Comment: Oh I see, so the only way around this is to use "replace" right? If that is so then thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user3414064 the best way is to use "query parameters", but it's more complex, check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/542542/1057961